# Xcode Button Going to the Wrong Link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

my app currently has two buttons. One leads to a Twitter page, and the other links to a page on my Website. They are both on the same view controller and same view. However, when I click the Feedback button, it goes to my Twitter. Any advice?

Here's my code.

```
import UIKit

class AboutScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func twitterButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url2 = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/SunnyParks4u") {
             UIApplication.shared.open(url2, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func FeedbackButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if let Contactlink = URL(string: "https://sunnyparks4u.wixsite.com/home-page/contact-8") {
             UIApplication.shared.open(Contactlink, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You copy/pasted the button in the interface builder and now both of the buttons executes the same IBAction.

Right-click on both buttons and check
[image]